# Jetpack: Unable to transition to other navigation.xml's fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm currently trying to transition to a Fragment in navigation2.xml to navigation.xml. I thought Reference other navigation graphs with  would do but doesn't work. If there is a sample or hints about transitioning between fragments of different navigation.xml files , I would love to hear from you!

```
<!-- (root) navigation.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/included_graph" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment"
        android:label="Fragment in Root Graph"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_to_second_graph"
            app:destination="@id/second_graph" />
    </fragment>

    ...
</navigation>
```

second navigation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/second_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/includedStart">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/includedStart"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.IncludedStart"
        android:label="fragment_included_start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_included_start" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: add some code here what you tried doing.

Comment: There is only two default navigation.xml and navigation2.xml. Since I don't know how to connect the basic, nothing is done. I need sample and hints because I can7t find a tutorial about it

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Design navigation graphs documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph#nested_graphs):

> [Nested graphs] also provide a level of encapsulation — destinations outside of the nested graph do not have direct access to any of the destinations within the nested graph. Instead, they should `navigate()` to the nested graph itself, where the internal logic can change without affecting the rest of the graph.

Therefore you can use `navigate(R.id.second_graph)` without issue from anywhere in `navigation.xml`, but you can't directly access anything *within* that other graph.

Note that the one exception to this is [navigating by URI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate_using_uri), which allows you to navigate to any destination in your graph (whether nested or not) by navigating using an [implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit).